# Approximate permutation block diagonalization for correlation matrices.

Tags: soft-question, covariance, correlation

I'm working with correlation matrices and I'd like to find such permutation of variables that the correlation matrix is 'most block diagonal' (cf. picture below). How does one go about doing this? Is there some well known metric that measures *'block-diagonalness'*?

I'm happy with any result that groups variables in a sensible way for clear-cut cases and doesn't do terrible job in vague ones.

[image: Desired matrix transformation]

Comment: "Denationalization" ?  I would try to minimize $\sum_{ij} |i-j|R_{ij}$ by swaps, until there was no improvement.

Comment: @kimchilover that's a typo. Overeager spellcheck. It's a possible idea. Can you do this faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: No, I can't.  I don't see how any algorithm could do this faster than $O(n^2)$, though.